# Switch from userA to userB

Tags: vscode-remote

In my situation, I first need to connect to a UserA then su - UserB in order to have access my files. But when I'm trying to connect with the extension it didn't recognize the server version.

```
Host some_name
  User  userA
  HostName  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  RemoteCommand "su - userB"
  RequestTTY yes
```

I got the following error message: unreachable or not Linux x86_64. (Cannot execute command-line and remote command.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling to solve the same problem. I've tried a bunch of different stuff to try and auth as `user b` *before* vscode connects to `userA`s remote connection server, such as:

- adding various additional parameters to my ssh config, authing as `userB` as above,
- adding a similar `su userB` command to `userA`'s bashrc file on the remote server,
- same for bash_profile.

... all to no avail. In all cases, whatever I do, the vscode remote session will be instantiated under the under-privileged `user a` account, with the remote server launched in `user a`'s user directory. If I auth through a standard terminal app, things work as expected and the `su userB` command triggers immediately after `userA` login. If I open a vscode terminal session in the same workspace (i.e. hit the plus sign in the same window as the ssh tunnelling session) and auth as `userB`, this also works but the session authed as `userA` persists unchanged.